# Ensure method was called with args at some point during test

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, expectations

I want to ensure that my `Foo.bar` method is called with `true` at some point during my test. So far I've only been able to assert against the **first call** to `Foo.bar`. I need to assert against **any call**.

This is what I have so far but doesn't work:

```
  expect(Foo).to receive(:bar).at_least(:once).with("true")

  Foo.bar("false")
  Foo.bar("false")
  Foo.bar("true")
  Foo.bar("false")
```

It fails on the first `Foo.bar` because "false" doesn't match my "true" expectation. How would you rewrite this to pass because `Foo.bar("true")` is called at **some** point during the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in this case you would need to do what I think of as the method stubbing equivalent of [`as_null_object`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/method-stubs/as-null-object):

```
describe Foo
  describe 'testing .bar multiple times' do
    before do
      allow(Foo).to receive(:bar) # stub out message
    end

    it "can determine how many times it has been called with 'true'" do
      expect(Foo).to receive(:bar).at_least(:once).with("true")
      expect(Foo).to receive(:bar).at_most(:once).with("true")
      Foo.bar("false")
      Foo.bar("false")
      Foo.bar("true")
      Foo.bar("false")
    end
  end
end
```